# Using Hibernate session with quartz

Tags: java, hibernate, struts, quartz-scheduler

I've a web application which uses framework like Struts and Hibernate. Currently I'm developing a scheduler for this application using Quartz. While coding I realized that the use of Hibernate session is not possible with the threads of Quartz.

Anybody have a solution for using hibernate sessions from quartz job class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use a [`HibernateUtil` class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-helpers) which builds the `SessionFactory` in a static initializer and makes it available via a `public static` getter. Your Quartz job can create a `Session` as `HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()` and use it.

Comment: My quartz job class is supposed to FTP to some remote servers and upload a large collection(millions) XML files to them. Is this the right method to follow for this scenario?

Comment: My code is producing lots of errors while running the hibernate from a quartz job. If I run it from outside the quartz, it works correctly and do all DB operations. What I need to change to make it working with quartz.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I did a quick Google search, and this was the first hit.

In the quartz job, add this line at the start of the method:

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException
{
    SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this); //<-- this line

     //...your code here...
}
```

I apologize if this doesn't fix your specific issue, but I suspect it will catch someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks a million for your answer. I was facing this problem from last few days and your answer solve my issues.... 

Thanks a million again

Answer (score 2):

Searching for "Quartz Hibernate" returned this. Coming to a different solution (and using Tapestry), I thought I'd share it.

when scheduling the Job:

```
…
Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler();
JobDataMap myJobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
myJobDataMap.put("HibernateSessionManager", hibernateSessionManager);
        myJobDataMap.put("PerthreadManager", perThreadManager);
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SomeJob.class).withIdentity(
            "SomeJob", "someGroup").setJobData(
            myJobDataMap).build();
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(
            "Some Trigger", "someGroup").startNow().withSchedule(
            SimpleScheduleBuilder.repeatSecondlyForever(30)).build();
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
scheduler.start();
…
```

and in the Job

```
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
                throws JobExecutionException
{
    JobDataMap jdm = context.getMergedJobDataMap();
    HibernateSessionManager hibernateSessionManager = (HibernateSessionManager) jdm.get("HibernateSessionManager");
    PerthreadManager perThreadManager = (PerthreadManager) jdm.get("PerthreadManager");

    Session session = hibernateSessionManager.getSession();
    //do stuff with session …
    //now clean up, otherwise I ended up with <IDLE> in transactions
    perThreadManager.cleanUp();
}
```

Hope somebody can use this.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the below link to see if it gives you a direction to follow. Since you are not using Spring, it might be hard to apply this directly

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=12117

Comment: I can use spring in this case, as I've very small amount of code in Struts.