# Insert data after completing job in Quartz scheduler using spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I'm working on a task in which I need to save job status in database but when I tried to do this it gives me `java.lang.nullpointerexception`. I think it happen because whenever I tried to select/save/update any record from the database only at that time it gives me error similar to this.

Here is my code

```
public class PostFBJob implements Job {

    private SchedulerService schedulerService;

    private SubCampaignService subCampaignService;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        JobDetail jobDetail = context.getJobDetail();
        JobDataMap jobDataMap = jobDetail.getJobDataMap();

        schedulerService = (SchedulerService) jobDataMap.get("schedulerService");

        SubCampaign subCampaign = (SubCampaign) jobDataMap.get("subCampaign");

        if (prStreamItem.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Facebook") && StringUtils.isNotBlank(branch.getFbAccessToken())) {
            FacebookService facebookService = FacebookService.getSingleton();
            try {
                subCampaign.setStatus("Completed");
                subCampaign.setMessage("Completed");

                subCampaignService.updateSubCampaign(subCampaign);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ace.Job.SubCampaignJob.execute(SubCampaignJob.java:147)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:213)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:557)
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help me to solve this issue. I'm new to Spring and Quartz.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please also provide whole exception in question .

Comment: NullPointerException is one of the easiest problems to debug: the stack trace tells you the file and line number at which it occurs.  A quick spin in a debugger will show you which reference has not been initialized properly.  Can't tell from the code you posted.  I see no database code here; updateSubCampaign is my best guess.

Comment: @developerbhuwan Thanks for replying. I only get `java.lang.NullPointerException` at this line `subCampaignService.updateSubCampaign(subCampaign);`

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for replying but sorry to say I'm not able to get any other detail. it's just throwing an error when I tried to get/update any record from the database...

Comment: Yes you are.  Use a debugger.  IntelliJ is the best IDE on the market, and they have a community version.  Go get it.  Debugging is a key skill that you have to develop in order to be a successful programmer.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks for your suggestion. I'll work on this but can you help me with this right now as it'l take a lot of time to go for your idea now

Comment: Nope.  You posted this question 47 minutes ago as I write this.  You would have found this and moved on already if you had a debugger and some idea of how to use it.  Even adding println output for each reference before you used it would have revealed this faster than asking at SO.

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen This question is totally different from the `nullpointerexception` because there is an error occured due to quartz controller which is not allowing me to access service layer from in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for is here

Please check below link

[Correct way to persist Quartz triggers in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402112/correct-way-to-persist-quartz-triggers-in-database)

And you can also check this link

[Using Hibernate session with quartz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446103/using-hibernate-session-with-quartz/27062640#27062640)

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would prefer Quartz over the built in Executor. It feels like an unnecessary dependency.

Comment: @duffymo Sorry, but I'm not able to understand what you want to say here. I answered this question because I think this is what he was looking for

Comment: This comment is not directed at you or criticism of your answer.  It's more of an observation than anything else.   I think Quartz is unnecessary since JDK7 and the concurrent package.

Answer (score 4):

This exception due to null object of subCampaignService.
Injection work only those objects which are managed by spring.

To scan your all packages where you want to use Service.

1. Annotation based configuration

   `@ComponentScan({"com.ace"})`
2. XML based configuration

   `<context:component-scan base-package="com.ace"/>`

And also check null before update like below:

```
try {
    subCampaign.setStatus("Completed");
    subCampaign.setMessage("Completed");
    if(subCampaign != null && subCampaignService != null) //Check is not null to subCampaign before update
    subCampaignService.updateSubCampaign(subCampaign);
} catch (Exception e) {
     log.error("", e);
}
```

Comment: Put `@Service` annotation in `SubCampaignService` class then check.

Comment: Check null as define in answer.

Comment: It's only causing issue when I tried to enter data from quartz scheduler otherwise it's working for me for other modules

Comment: Check this it's gives me error at the following line
`subCampaignService.updateSubCampaign(subCampaign);`

Comment: `public PostFBJob(SubCampaignService  subCampaignService ) {
     this.subCampaignService = subCampaignService
    }` add this in this class and then check

Comment: This is not giving me any error and I'm also able to access data in the given function but when I tried to update record in database got same exception

Comment: Add `e.printStackTrace();` line of code in catch block and paste whole exception in question. This do for me brother.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I just updated my question with the full exception message

Comment: It's due to subCampaignService is null so to detect error please also provide Spring Configuration Setting on your app.

Comment: I think it's not because of subCampaignService is null. I think it's because of quartz scheduler is not allowing you to execute database query here..

Comment: @developerbhuwan Is com.ace is the name of service package.. Please tell me I'm facing same issue

Comment: @Zoro please send me detail problem in my skype id: developerbhuwan

Comment: Yes com.ace is package name in your application.